# C# unit test boolean

Tags: c#, unit-testing, boolean

I need help on writing a unit test for this

```
Public static Boolean InList(byte value, Type t)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(t, value))
    {
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is what i written so far but it keep given me error "out of bound"

```
  [TestMethod()]
  Public void InListTest()
  {
     Assert.IsTrue(ValidationUI.InList(1, Type.EmptyTypes[0]));
  }
```

I don't expect what I wrote on unit test is what the test is asking for, i need some guidance. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Type.EmptyTypes` is an _empty_ array of types - so `Type.EmptyTypes[0]` will throw an index-out-of-bounds exception.  What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: To D Stanley you listen!  Also, simplify your **InList()** method to one line: **return Enum.IsDefined(t, value)**

Comment: Yes, but if i dont, it said it needed a value. I just dont know the proper inut in the parameters of byte and type

Comment: Do you understand what the _method_ does?  If not, it's very hard to write a good test for it...

Comment: I kinda understand, but i was hoping for a better explanation

Comment: Can't a newbie asking a question here without getting a -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will test your method:

```
public enum TestEnum : byte {
  One = 1,
  Two = 2
}

[TestMethod()]
Public void InListTest()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(ValidationUI.InList(1, typeof(TestEnum));
    Assert.IsFalse(ValidationUI.InList(100, typeof(TestEnum));
}
```